# Is there a pair of Spanish words that only differ in a diaeresis over "u"?

Tags: ortografía

As user [@pablodf76](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/14627/pablodf76) said in [an answer to another question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/25697/12637):

> Leaving out the accent marks seldom produces confusion, but it may pose a problem in some cases. *Sí* ("yes") vs. *si* ("if") is one notorious case. The diaeresis over *ü* is definitely not a problem. I'll be hard-pressed to think of a word that could conceivably be misread due to its missing a diaeresis over *u*.

So I wonder, is there a pair of Spanish words that only differ in a diaeresis over *u*, so that the diaeresis is needed to tell them apart?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

| gu | gü |
| --- | --- |
| [coligue](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9mfhZTD) | [coligüe](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9moBxac) |
| [guifa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JoyeGlu) | [güifa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JoyvpEc) |
| [guija](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JozuEom) | [güija](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Jp2YTUb) |
| [guipe](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Jr7zgmv) | [güipe](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Jr9pNFb) |
| [guincha](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JpuXHbo) | [güincha](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JpuBhDR) |
| [guinche](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JpuXHbo) | [güinche](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JpuBhDR)/[guinche](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JpvLCn8%5D) |
| [guito](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JsLQqfq)/[guito](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Js4gu0Z) | [güito](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JsLQvVF) |
| [higuera](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KNmlooy%7CKNoqKXx) | higüera ([güira](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JrFjlrE))<sup>1</sup> |
| [pingue](http://dle.rae.es/?id=T3Kf3iD)/[pingue](http://dle.rae.es/?id=T3YZlm7) | [pingüe](http://dle.rae.es/?id=T3Zh4yS) |

And noting [*higuela*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KNj75F6)/[*higüela*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KNlL7KL) can be spelt with or without the diaeresis.

---

<sup>**1.** [https://www.fundeu.es/noticia/de-higueras-e-higüeras-5618/](https://www.fundeu.es/noticia/de-higueras-e-higueras-5618/)</sup>

Comment: ¡_guifa_ viene de carroña! :O nunca un apodo de alguien mejoró tanto un significado

Comment: @fedorqui ahora le toca a guifa explicar el porqué de su apodo. :-) Nunca pensé que era una palabra del español.

Comment: @DGaleano yo sigo apostando por que su nombre empieza por "gui" y su apellido por "fa"...

Comment: Hay que reconocer que en ningún caso se trata de un par de palabras comunes, de las que la mayoría de los hispano-hablantes reconocemos.

Answer (score 8):

I have found this pair of words:

> **[guito, ta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JsLQqfq)**
>
> De *guitón*.
>
> 1. adj. Ar. Dicho de un animal de carga: Que es falso.
>
> **[güito](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JsLQvVF)**
>
> 1. m. Hueso de una fruta, especialmente de albaricoque.
> 2. m. Pito que fabrican los niños con el hueso de un albaricoque.
> 3. m. coloq. sombrero (‖ prenda para la cabeza).

Answer (score 4):

*Garguero* admite las dos formas: [*garguero*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IuTn98e) y [*gargüero*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IuVRAjc).

Comment: Técnicamente esto sí podría valer como respuesta. Vale que ambas palabras sean dos formas correctas de representar el mismo concepto, y por tanto no sea necesario diferenciar ambas formas, pero siempre queda la duda de cuál de las dos formas era la que quería usar el autor original si se supone que en el texto en el que se encuentra se han omitido todas las tildes y diéresis.

Comment: ...y es curioso que la RAE refiere la palabra con dieresis a la que no la tiene, como si en lugar de originalmente tenerla y haberla perdido hubiera sido al contrario.