# Does Mexican Spanish use grave accents?

Tags: ortografía, méxico, diacríticos

I was taught that, besides ñ, the only diacritics in Castilian are acute accents on vowels, to indicate the atypical placement of stress.

In subtitles for the English version of the Mexico-based 2017 film *Coco*, which also has occasional Spanish, I sometimes see vowels with grave accents instead. Examples include *espèrame* instead of *espérame*, *dejarè* instead of *dejaré*, and *què* instead of *qué*.

Are these typos, or is Mexican Spanish different in this regard?

Comment: i haven't understood the grave or accute accents, someone should record himself to explain the difference between this accents if they were used in spanish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Spanish (of any standard written variety) only uses acute accents in these circumstances. This seems like an error on the subtitles.

See, for example, on the official Latin American Disney channel on YouTube it employs [only acute accents](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-BXENhoU3rQ) in the videos' (hardcoded) subtitles:

[image: Coco Tráiler]

You may *occasionally* see grave accents in some proper nouns in Spanish derived from other languages (e.g. some towns in Catalonia: *Puigcerdà* `Catalan`, *Bossòst* `Aranese`), but even in these cases they mostly also have Spanishised versions ([*Puigcerdá*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puigcerd%C3%A1), [*Bosost*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bosost)).

**Note:** in addition to *ñ* <sup>1</sup>, *á, é, í, ó, ú* <sup>2</sup> there is also [*ü*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/25700/18348) to show a 'u' is pronounced when occurring between a 'g' and an 'e' or 'i' e.g. *lingüística, güey*.

---

<sup>**1.** Not recognised as an 'accent' by natives, but a distinct letter from *n*. Similar to how in English 'j' isn't seen as just an 'i' with a tail.</sup>

<sup>**2.** Also *ý* occurs in a handful of [archaic proper nouns](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20262/18348).</sup>