# What changes can I expect/anticipate in IM chatting or short messages?

Tags: vocabulario

From time to time I see *pedantically wrong* language in online forums and short messages, for example missing diacritics above letters, sometimes including the tilde above **ñ**. Also there are some places where a single Q appears, and I think it's a short form of *que*:

> quiero saber l q ha pasado (I want to know what happened)

What difference may I anticipate between grammatically correct language and daily/casual typing?

Comment: This could be an interesting question, but I suspect people is not paying attention to it because it is too broad to answer. Besides, there can be regional differences in the way people uses these abbreviations. I suggest to narrow the scope of the question and ask for specific texts you may have problems to understand. Nonetheless, I see that you got the meaning of your example sentence quite right.

Comment: I bet you could give yourself a crash course in internet abbreviations and sloppy writing by reading (a) La Tertulia (our chat area here at Spanish Language Beta) and Yahoo Respuestas.

Comment: I wonder about that phrase "pedantically wrong."  Do you really mean that?

Comment: @aparente001 *be pedantic* = *be strict about grammar*

Comment: Somehow related: [How important are accents in written Spanish?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/84/1674)

Answer (score 3):

I will try to be concise but there are many changes ...

> The most common changes:

- **The comma between the subject and the predicate:**

  This error tends to mark, in some cases, a spoken pause, but it is necessary to remember that the punctuation marks do not correspond to the pauses that take place in the oral discourse.

  Example: "Todos los actores, tomaran una copa tras la función"
- **Queism** (`queismo`):
  As well as dequeísmo is to add the preposition of when it has not to be(`Me contó de que se iba a Córdoba`), queism is the opposite, to omit (`Me alegro que te hayan dado el trabajo`.
- **Do not put accents on pronouns:**
  We're not going to be theoretical, it's just a very common mistake
- **Abusive use of commas**
- **the confusion between «a ver» and «haber»:**
  This one in particular gives me a lot of revulsion, because I see it written very frequently and not only in those ways, but also in incorrect ways that are obvious and nobody cares.
- **Forget the `H` and change the `K` for the `C` and the `QU` **
- **The correct use of «Ay!», «hay» and «ahí»:** Very common especially in the smallest that only use the «hay».
- **Terms and abbreviations:** Here I will point out, it is very common in internet texts or chats to abbreviate or simply to use fewer characters in a way that is understood, even though each word is misspelled.

These cases are many and I give you some examples:

---

- Aki: aquí
- Xq: porque
- Nd: nada
- Bn: bien
- Gns: ganas
- Jum: expresión que significa enfado
- Qtpsa: ¿qué te pasa?
- Tw: tweet
- Fb: Facebook
- Wp o wasa: Whatsapp
- Wenas: buenas, hola
- Ola ke ase: hola, ¿qué haces?
- Xa, pa: para
- `+`: más
- `-`: menos
- `=` : igual

This is only a few of them, there are more than i can remember.

---

- **Forget the ¿ at the begining of the question:** Quite common - `A que hora quedamos?`

There are pretty more, but less common in my opinion.

Comment: +1 Good start on this

Comment: Grx= Gracias. Obviously always try to use the right grammar and spelling. :-)